# Writing to a Shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile

I'm having trouble writing/reading a Shapefile in python. I have an array of points that I would like to write to a polygon using pyshp.  The relevant parts of the code are:

```
dividedRects = [(7598325.0, 731579.0, 7698325.0, 631579.0), (7598325.0, 631579.0, 7698325.0, 611641.0), (7698325.0, 731579.0, 7728636.0, 631579.0), (7698325.0, 631579.0, 7728636.0, 611641.0)]

def createPolys(dividedRects):
    w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
    for i in range(0, len(dividedRects)):
        print i
        topLeft = [dividedRects[i][0],dividedRects[i][1]]
        topRight = [dividedRects[i][2], dividedRects[i][1]]
        bottomRight = [dividedRects[i][2], dividedRects[i][3]]
        bottomLeft = [dividedRects[i][0], dividedRects[i][3]]
        w.poly(parts=[[topLeft,topRight,bottomRight,bottomLeft]])
        w.field("ID", "C", "40")
        w.field("Events", "C", "40")
        w.record(str(i), str(0))
    w.save('cellFile')

createPolys(dividedRects)
```

This causes an error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-503affbe838b> in <module>()
----> 1 createPolys(dividedRects)

<ipython-input-35-4c552ae29bc7> in createPolys(dividedRects)
     10         w.field("ID", "C", "40")
     11         w.field("Events", "C", "40")
---> 12         w.record(str(i), str(0))
     13     w.save('cellFile')
     14 #     topLeft = [dividedRects[1][0],dividedRects[1][1]]

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\shapefile.pyc in record(self, *recordList, **recordDict)
    967         if self.fields[0][0].startswith("Deletion"): fieldCount -= 1
    968         if recordList:
--> 969             [record.append(recordList[i]) for i in range(fieldCount)]
    970         elif recordDict:
    971             for field in self.fields:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If I remove the `field` and `records` lines from `createPolys`:

```
def createPolys(dividedRects):
    w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
    for i in range(0, len(dividedRects)):
        print i
        topLeft = [dividedRects[i][0],dividedRects[i][1]]
        topRight = [dividedRects[i][2], dividedRects[i][1]]
        bottomRight = [dividedRects[i][2], dividedRects[i][3]]
        bottomLeft = [dividedRects[i][0], dividedRects[i][3]]
        w.poly(parts=[[topLeft,topRight,bottomRight,bottomLeft]])
#         w.field("ID", "C", "40")
#         w.field("Events", "C", "40")
#         w.record(str(i), str(0))
    w.save('cellFile')
```

Then I get an assertionerror when reading the records from the file:

```
createPolys(dividedRects)

sf2 = shapefile.Reader("cellFile")
print sf2.records()
shapes = sf2.shapes()
bbox = shapes[1].bbox
#['%.3f' % coord for coord in bbox]
print bbox
points = shapes[1].points
print points

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-597af0b882ba> in <module>()
      1 sf2 = shapefile.Reader("cellFile")
----> 2 print sf2.records()
      3 shapes = sf2.shapes()
      4 bbox = shapes[1].bbox
      5 #['%.3f' % coord for coord in bbox]

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\shapefile.pyc in records(self)
    528         """Returns all records in a dbf file."""
    529         if not self.numRecords:
--> 530             self.__dbfHeader()
    531         records = []
    532         f = self.__getFileObj(self.dbf)

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\shapefile.pyc in __dbfHeader(self)
    464             self.fields.append(fieldDesc)
    465         terminator = dbf.read(1)
--> 466         assert terminator == b("\r")
    467         self.fields.insert(0, ('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1, 0))
    468 

AssertionError:
```

When I removed the loop and wrote one record it seemed to work ok.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about `pyshp` library, but I'll try to help anyways.

The two `w.field()` commands occur in the `for` loop.  This may cause the two columns "ID" and "Events" to be defined multiple times.  When you write only one record (polygon), it works fine (i.e. the `w.record()` command contains two values).  After the first iteration, there would be 4, 6, etc columns.  That would explain the behavior you describe.

Try moving the two `w.field()` lines before the `for loop`.

When you comment the `w.record()`, you obtain a `shp` (and `shx`) file with a number of records different from the corresponding `dbf`file.  That explains the assertion error when reading.

Unrelated to your problem, you could also simplify your code with `enumerate` (built-in function).

```
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
w.field("ID", "C", "40")
w.field("Events", "C", "40")    
for i,rect1 in enumerate(dividedRects):
    print i
    topLeft = [rect1[0],rect1[1]]
    topRight = [rect1[2], rect1[1]]
    bottomRight = [rect1[2], rect1[3]]
    bottomLeft = [rect1[0], rect1[3]]
    ....
```

(I cannot test since I do not have `pyshp`)  Good luck!

Comment: That did it, thanks!  I can't believe that I didn't see that, though I've been looking at if for hours...